# How to subtract one vector from another vector in r

Tags: r

I have a vector `c <- c(1,2,3)` and another vector `d <- c(4,5,6,7)`. I want to subtract each element of `c` from  each element of `d` to get a `list` of lists in R. How can I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 4:6

a - b
# [1] -3 -3 -3
```

That is a basic question, please consider reading [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf).

EDIT:

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 4:7
lapply(a, function(x)x-b)
# [[1]]
# [1] -3 -4 -5 -6
# [[2]]
# [1] -2 -3 -4 -5
# [[3]]
# [1] -1 -2 -3 -4
```

Comment: No answer should be c(c(-3,-4,-5,-6),c(-2,-3,-4,-5),c(-1,-2,-3,-4)).

Comment: @Sumit: Sorry, but I didn't understand your question first. See my edit.

Answer (score 7):

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 4:7
lapply(x, `-`, y)
[[1]]
[1] -3 -4 -5 -6

[[2]]
[1] -2 -3 -4 -5

[[3]]
[1] -1 -2 -3 -4
```

Answer (score 3):

`outer` does this if you're satisfied with a `matrix` instead of a `list` for your results:

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 4:7

outer(a, b, "-")
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]   -3   -4   -5   -6
# [2,]   -2   -3   -4   -5
# [3,]   -1   -2   -3   -4
```